# Which bootloader to use when dual booting a Mac without OSX (Win/Ubuntu)

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, boot-camp, efi

A while back I used Bootcamp to install Windows 8 on my 2011 27' iMac. Accidentally using the Windows installer I overwrote Windows onto my OSX partition. Now I would like to install Ubuntu on to my second partition, I have used Wubi to install it and now im not sure where to go. I cannot install REFIT because I have no OSX partition and I cant access Ubuntu through holding option on boot. Which bootloader should I use?

Comment: Does Ubuntu not show in the Windows loader?  Typically using WUBI, Ubuntu is added to the windows "longhorn" loader.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac that lacks an OS X installation, the best approach is typically to treat the computer as a BIOS machine: Use a BIOS-mode boot loader like LILO or GRUB and a [Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition scheme with no hint of a [GUID Partition Table (GPT).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) On such a configuration, a WUBI-based installation *should* work, so if it's not working, you should describe precisely what's going wrong. You might also try running the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from a Linux emergency disc and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it creates. This will give us more information about how your disk is partitioned and what boot loaders are installed.

One more comment: Given your description of how you got to your current situation, I suspect you may have a damaged partition table, or at least one that could easily become damaged should you use the wrong tools on it. This is another reason to post the Boot Info Script's `RESULTS.txt` file, since it will reveal (to those who know how to read it) whether this is the case.